# How do you complete level 11?

Tags: vim-adventures

I am stuck at the end of level 11:

1) How to delete the "you deleted reality" in 6 key stokes?
2) Where do I find the Red key for the underground?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to "delete reality". These are simply provided for yanking. In regards of the red key here is a quote from the author:

> Make sure you change the Open Sesame on Arrow Island according to the
>   hints (and not just type them in). It's like in level 5 when you can
>   edit the text, but the ranges are not shown.

Answer (score 1):

1. As @firedev said, you don't need to delete reality.  Those are there to let you get text into the "register" (similar to "clipboard") for pasting, before you have the **y** key for "yanking" (similar to "copying").
2. At the end of level 11, you get the red key by changing **Open Sesame** to **:e underground**.  A red key and an NPC with a helpful hint then appear.